# ActiveExplorer().Selection returns previously selected mail in Outlook C#

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I've following code. When user clicks on Reply or Reply button, it will pass the original email which will be process on SendAndComplete button.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public object selectedObject = null;
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Application application = this.Application;
            Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = application.ActiveExplorer();

            //Get this event fire when selection changes
            currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
        }

        public void CurrentExplorer_Event()
        {
            if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1
             && this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] is Outlook.MailItem)
            {

                selectedObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                mailItem = selectedObject as Outlook.MailItem;
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).ReplyAll += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(MailItem_ReplyAll);
            }
        }

        void MailItem_Reply(object response, ref bool cancel)
        {
            //No code here

        }

        void MailItem_ReplyAll(object response, ref bool cancel)
        {
            //No code here
        }
    }
```

Now the `selectedObject` will be used on Ribbon.cs on button click.

```
public void SendnCompleteButton_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
            var addIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = addIn.selectedObject as Outlook.MailItem;
            MessageBox.Show(mailItem.Subject + " " + mailItem.ReceivedTime + " " + mailItem.Sender.Name)
        }
```

Message box is showing previously selected email, how do I release the previously selected object?

Thank you.

Comment: "previously selected"  in what sense? Do you mean SelectionChange event does not fire and thus you end up with an old selection?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes SelectionChange did not fire up. For some reason message box kept showing first email which I had selected when I first compiled. Eugene's suggestion helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance in the ribbon button's event handler:

```
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
```

Instead, you need to use the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` property or just the add-in class which provides the `Application` property out of the box.

Second, you must declare the event source object at the global scope, for example:

```
Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();

            //Get this event fire when selection changes
            currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
        }
```

Third, checking whether a single item is selected in Outlook UI is not correct. Instead, you should check whether any item is selected:

```
if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
```

Comment: I have another issue and I was wondering if you can help. I need to hold the `mailItem` until user sends reply. But if in between user selects any other email, the `mailItem` would change to the new selection because of `currentExplorer.SelectionChange`. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You can create a list of object - for example: `List<MailItem>`

Comment: If I understand correctly, create `List<MailItem>` and add each item whichever triggers with `SelectionChange` and then how do I retrieve the original one which I am replying to?