# How to: Programmatically determine the current Outlook item for new event handler

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

As the subject suggests, I am trying to determine if an Outlook item is a meeting request, while creating a new .ItemSend event handler.  I have looked at ways of doing this with inspector and explorer.

I have reviewed this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-outlook-item?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

and this:

[ActiveExplorer().Selection returns previously selected mail in Outlook C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415144/activeexplorer-selection-returns-previously-selected-mail-in-outlook-c-sharp)

as well as a few of the 'similar questions'.

I have been successful with establishing a new inspector event handler as well as defining the event handler for Application.ItemSend and those are working great.  But only when I send meeting requests.  Regular emails respond to the event triggers, but restart Outlook, saving an email as a draft, without sending.

I am not sure of combining the use of inspector and explorer to prevent crashing Outlook?  I am not sure if I can do this by only using inspector?  By only using explorer?

I believe that if I can wrap all of this code with identification of an outlook item as a MailItem or a Meeting Request, I can get around this problem I am having with emails and the new event handler.

A point in  the right direction is appreciated.
Thanks - - chris

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors = null;
        private Outlook.UserProperty objUserPropertyEventId = null;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
            // define event handler for ItemSend
            Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Note:      Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
            //              must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            // <testing this>
            Outlook.Selection sel = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

            if (sel.Count == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("One selected");

            //Outlook.MailItem mail = sel[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
            Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

            //if (mail != null)
            if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                MessageBox.Show("This is a mail item."/*\n\n" + mail.Subject*/);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("This is NOT a mail item."/*\n\n" + mail.Subject*/);
            // </testing this>

            // <this works, but not for email.  Only meeting requests.>
            #pragma warning disable IDE0019 // Use pattern matching
            Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            #pragma warning restore IDE0019 // Use pattern matching

            // is it an AppointmentItem
            if (appt != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("appt != null");
                // is it a meeting request
                if (appt.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting)
                {
                    // force time of initial meeting dialog to be 11:29pm
                    // to avoid immediate reminder of upcoming meeting
                    DateTime datDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    
                    string strYear = datDateTime.ToString().Substring(6, 4);
                    int intYear;
                    intYear = Int32.Parse(strYear);

                    string strMonth = datDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Substring(0, 2);
                    int intMonth;
                    intMonth = Int32.Parse(strMonth);

                    string strDay = datDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Substring(3, 2);
                    int intDay;
                    intDay = Int32.Parse(strDay);

                    string strReqAtt = appt.RequiredAttendees;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strReqAtt))
                        appt.Start = new DateTime(intYear, intMonth, intDay, 23, 29, 00);

                    // save to generate EntryId for future reference
                    appt.Save();

                    // save EntryId as UserProperty
                    Outlook.AppointmentItem mtg;
                    mtg = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;

                    if (mtg != null)
                    {
                        if (mtg is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                        {
                            mtg.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
                            string strEntryId = mtg.EntryID;

                            Outlook.UserProperties objUserProperties = mtg.UserProperties;
                            objUserPropertyEventId = objUserProperties.Add("MeetingEntryId", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, 1);
                            objUserPropertyEventId.Value = strEntryId;
                        }
                    }
                    if (mtg != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mtg);
                }
                if (appt != null)
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appt);
            }
        }

        public void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            // use EventId to identify current meeting request
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            var ns = app.Session;

            Outlook.AppointmentItem meeting = ns.GetItemFromID(objUserPropertyEventId.Value);
            MessageBox.Show(meeting.Subject);
            //if (meeting.MeetingStatus != Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olNonMeeting)
            if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting)
            {
                // is ItemSend a request or a cancel
                if (meeting.MeetingStatus != Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("MeetingStatus != olMeetingCanceled");
                    Outlook.Recipient recipConf = null;
                    try
                    {
                        // ItemSend is a request
                        if (meeting is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                        {
                            //if (meeting.MeetingStatus == Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting)
                            {
                                Outlook.Recipient recipRoomUser;
                                // if a location was provided
                                if (meeting.Location != null)
                                {
                                    string strLocation = meeting.Location;
                                    bool blnTorF = false;
                                    string strConference = "|";

                                    // Clears lazy room number typing
                                    // Location resource:
                                    // places meeting on 'JHP Conference ###' calendar
                                    // and
                                    // sends email to conference room user with link for Teams meeting
                                    //      conference room user is added to 'Location' by including email in 'Required'
                                    if (!strLocation.Contains("Room - Conference"))
                                        meeting.Location = "";

                                    // Add calendar users (based on room location) to email
                                    // sends email to conference room user with link for Teams meeting
                                    //      conference room user is added to previously cleared 'Location'
                                    //      by including email in 'Required'
                                    if (strLocation.Contains("142"))
                                    {
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
                                        if(meeting.Location == "")
                                            meeting.Location = "xxx@xxx.com";
                                    }
                                    if (strLocation.Contains("150"))
                                    {
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
                                        if (meeting.Location == "")
                                            meeting.Location = "xxx@xxx.com";
                                    }
                                    if (strLocation.Contains("242"))
                                    {
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
                                        if (meeting.Location == "")
                                            meeting.Location = "xxx@xxx.com";
                                    }
                                    if (strLocation.Contains("248"))
                                    {
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser = meeting.Recipients.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
                                        recipRoomUser.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
                                        if (meeting.Location == "")
                                            meeting.Location = "xxx@xxx.com";
                                    }
                                    MessageBox.Show("Location assigned");

                                    // build string of recipients for .Split('|') to array
                                    foreach (Outlook.Recipient objUser in meeting.Recipients)
                                    {
                                        // remove previous location prior to room change
                                        if (!objUser.Name.Contains("JHP Conference") && !objUser.Name.Contains("Room - Conference"))
                                            if (!strConference.Contains(objUser.Name)) // no duplicates
                                                strConference = strConference + objUser.Name + "|";
                                    }

                                    if (strConference != "|")
                                    {
                                        // create array from string without duplicates
                                        //MessageBox.Show("strConference != |\n\n" + strConference);
                                        string[] arrConference = null;
                                        strConference = strConference.TrimStart('|');
                                        arrConference = strConference.Split('|');

                                        // verify array contents
                                        string strCheck = "";
                                        string strReqdAtts = "";
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arrConference.Length - 1; i++)
                                        {
                                            strCheck = strCheck + arrConference[i] + "\n";
                                            strReqdAtts = strReqdAtts + ";" + arrConference[i];
                                        }

                                        //MessageBox.Show("Array contents\n\n" + strCheck);
                                        strReqdAtts = strReqdAtts.TrimStart(';');
                                        //MessageBox.Show("RequiredAttendees contents\n\n" + strReqdAtts);
                                        meeting.RequiredAttendees = strReqdAtts;
                                        //MessageBox.Show(".Add");
                                    }
                                    MessageBox.Show("Attendees assigned");


                                    Cancel = true;
                                    // has the user included "JHP - Room Reservations" for placement
                                    // on the shared calendar for all conference room availability
                                    foreach (Outlook.Recipient objUser in meeting.Recipients)
                                    {
                                        if (objUser.Name == "JHP - Room Reservations")
                                            blnTorF = true;
                                    }
                                    // add "JHP - Room Reservations" if not already included
                                    if (blnTorF == false)
                                    {
                                        recipConf = meeting.Recipients.Add("JHP - Room Reservations");
                                        recipConf.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
                                    }
                                    // resolve recipients
                                    meeting.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                                    meeting.Send();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Calendar recipients were not added.");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (recipConf != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipConf);
                    }
                }
                else
                //{
                    // ItemSend is a cancel
                    MessageBox.Show("Meeting is cancelled.");
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a meeting");
            }
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Comments from both of you were helpful to me for getting my add-in to pre-process meeting requests and not pre-process anything else that Outlook may send.
Big thanks to both of you!
chris

Answer (score 1):

`AppointmentItem` object is never sent, and hence is never passed to the `Application.ItemSend` event handler. What you get is the `MeetingItem` object. If you need the parent appointment, call `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the `Explorer` window when the `NewInspector` event is fired:

```
 void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            // <testing this>
            Outlook.Selection sel = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
```

Use the `Inspector` instance passed as a parameter to the event handler instead.

Also I've noticed the following code in the `ItemSend` event handler:

```
 public void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            // use EventId to identify current meeting request
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            var ns = app.Session;
```

There is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance each time the event is fired. Use the `Application` property of your add-in class instead (available in the `ThisAddIn` class).

Also you need to use the `Item` object passed as a parameter to the ItemSend event handler, so instead of using the following code:

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem meeting = ns.GetItemFromID(objUserPropertyEventId.Value);
            MessageBox.Show(meeting.Subject);
```

Check whether an object is of a specific type:

```
if (Item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
```

You may try to cast the `Item` object to a specific type and then check for `null`:

```
var obj = Item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
if (obj != null)
{
  'do your work here
}
```